# How can I import Angular2 components compiled to a single file

Tags: typescript, angular, gulp, bundle

I'm trying to integrate Angular2 into Laravel. I'm following the [Quick Start guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html). I've configured elixir-typescript to compile all my typescript files into a single `app.js`. I run `gulp` and everything compiles correctly. If I visit my page in the browser I get this error in the console:

```
Error loading http://localhost/app/app.component.js as 
 "./app.component" from http://localhost/app/app.js ng:16:49
```

This is my `app.component.ts` file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '<h1>My First Laravel-Angular 2 App</h1>'
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

This is my `main.ts` file

```
///<reference path="../../../typings/index.d.ts"/>
import { bootstrap }    from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

The output file (`app.js`) is:

```
"use strict";
var __decorate = (this && this.__decorate) || function (decorators, target, key, desc) {
    var c = arguments.length, r = c < 3 ? target : desc === null ? desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, key) : desc, d;
    if (typeof Reflect === "object" && typeof Reflect.decorate === "function") r = Reflect.decorate(decorators, target, key, desc);
    else for (var i = decorators.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) if (d = decorators[i]) r = (c < 3 ? d(r) : c > 3 ? d(target, key, r) : d(target, key)) || r;
    return c > 3 && r && Object.defineProperty(target, key, r), r;
};
var __metadata = (this && this.__metadata) || function (k, v) {
    if (typeof Reflect === "object" && typeof Reflect.metadata === "function") return Reflect.metadata(k, v);
};
var core_1 = require('@angular/core');
var AppComponent = (function () {
    function AppComponent() {
    }
    AppComponent = __decorate([
        core_1.Component({
            selector: 'my-app',
            template: '<h1>My First Laravel-Angular 2 App</h1>'
        }),
        __metadata('design:paramtypes', [])
    ], AppComponent);
    return AppComponent;
}());
exports.AppComponent = AppComponent;

"use strict";
///<reference path="../../../typings/index.d.ts"/>
var platform_browser_dynamic_1 = require('@angular/platform-browser-dynamic');
var app_component_1 = require('./app.component');
platform_browser_dynamic_1.bootstrap(app_component_1.AppComponent);

//# sourceMappingURL=app.js.map
```

**If I change the second-to-last line** from:

```
var app_component_1 = require('./app.component');
```

to:

```
var app_component_1 = require('./app.js');
```

**My app works correctly** and I can see the component rendered in the page. I cannot figure out how to make my `main.ts` compile to this however. If I change the typescript `main.ts` to import from `'./app.js'` the typescript compiler fails.

I think the problem is that my gulpfile is just concatenating the compiled typescript files into one but its not doing anything to bundle them. How can I configure the typescript compiler to bundle every component into one single `.js` file and then be able to access everything from within my app?

I think the relevant lines in the `tsconfig.json` are these:

```
{ 
  ...,
  "module": "commonjs",
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For you to prevent the js files to compile into a single file, go to 
node_modules/elixir-typescript/index.js and comment this line .pipe($.concat(paths.output.name)).

Comment: That's what I'm doing but I don't want to. Wouldn't having a single file minimize server requests? Is there any advantage of having them be separate files?